# Change Label in uiComponent depending on Create/Edit mode

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I'm using the same ui component for the create/edit of my custom entity. I'm not sure how to change the fieldset label depending on whether im editing or creating a new entity. So for example, If im creating, the label would be 'Add New Slide', and if im editing it would 'Edit (Slide Name)'.

My uiComponent for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">slides_save.slides_form_date_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">slides_save.slides_form_date_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save Slide</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">AppFactory\Basic\Block\Adminhtml\Slides\BackButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">AppFactory\Basic\Block\Adminhtml\Slides\SaveButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="slides_form_date_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AppFactory\Basic\Model\SlidesDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">slides_form_date_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">banner_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="appfactory/slides/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="slide">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add a new Slide</item>
            </item>  <!-- This is the field im trying to change -->
        </argument>

        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Eanbled</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yes</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

     <field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slide Image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">2097152</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">AppFactory_Basic/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">appfactory/slides/uploadimage</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>





    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `DataProvider` class (`AppFactory\Basic\Model\SlidesDataProvider` in your case), add `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` as a dependency by adding it to the constructor:

```
protected $request

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ...
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    ...
}
```

now create a method called `getMeta` with this code:

```
public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();

    if (!is_null($this->request->getParam($this->getRequestFieldName(), null)))
    {
        $meta['slide']['arguments']['data']['config']['label'] = "Edit Slide";
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

This will check if the request contains an id param (which signifies editing) and if so will change the label of the fieldset.